# On Premise - Kubernetes External Endpoint for services

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We are analyzing the integration of the [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) service in our on premise environment. We have SaaS based services which can be exposed publicly.

We have doubts in setting up the external endpoints for the services. Is there any way to create the external endpoints for the services?

We have tried to setup the `ExternalIP` parameter in the services with the master node IP address. Not sure this is the correct way. Once we setup the external IP with the master node IP address we are able to access the services.

We have also tried with ingress controllers and also there we can access our services with the IP address of the node where the ingress controllers are running.

For Example :

```
Public IP : XXX.XX.XX.XX
```

Ideally, we would map the public IP with the load balancer virtual IP, but we cannot find such a setting in Kubernetes.

Is there any way to address this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use an Ingress Controller that acts as a proxy for all your services in kubernetes.

Of course your ingress controller has to be somehow exposed to the outside world. My suggestion is to use the `hostNetwork` setting for the ingress controller pod (this way, the pod will be listening on your host's physical interface, like any other "traditional" service).

A few resources:

- [Here](http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/) details on how a pod can be reached from outside your k8s cluster).
- [Here](https://medium.com/@samwalker505/using-kubernetes-ingress-controller-from-scratch-35faeee8eca) a nice tutorial on how to setup an ingress controller on k8s.

If you have more than one minion in your cluster, you'll end up having problems with load balancing them. [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/869413/whats-the-common-practice-of-managing-the-external-ip-of-a-docker-swarm/869506#869506) can be helpful about that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let me try it out

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078969/whites11, I can set the ingress controllers as per your suggestion. I have one more doubt,

Would it also be possible to allow listening to multiple ports (e.g. 8443 and 8080) and then forward incoming requests to https://demo.example.com:8443 to service1 and http://demo.example.com:8080 to service2 in kubernetes ingress controllers?